# @Command([EditCopy]) in LotusScript

Tags: lotus-domino, lotusscript, lotus-formula

I can't find a way to copy selected documents to buffer using standard classes in LotusScript.
Is it possible to do it?

```
@Command([EditCopy])
```

The problem with command/formula - is more difficult to debug/log errors etc, so I wish to re-write action to LotusScript if possible.

I can make a solution via Java and then wrap it into LS2J, but it looks to complicated for such simple operation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't copy selected documents to clipboard with standard LotusScript Notes classes.

NotesUiDocument.Copy() doesn't help you neither as it copies only selected parts of an open document.

I would stay with @Command([EditCopy]). If it's *really* worth it to move the formula code to LotusScript I would separate @Command([EditCopy]) in an agent and call it from your new LotusScript code.

But, the question is, what is the goal to copy selected documents to clipboard? It will be a Notes Client specific kind of clipboard content. You can only use it in Notes Client itself to copy the documents into the same or another database. So, why not use "normal" LotusScript methods to copy documents like NotesDocument.CopyToDatabase or NotesDocument.CopyAllItems?

Comment: Customer would like to show 'msgbox' with information "number of selected documents have been copied to buffer". Notifications (title, body) are stored as a document in another database. Notification has also some tags ($date, $time, $username etc).
The logic that handle everything (building msg + replacing tags) are  in LotusScript.
Of course we can do this in @Formula - but that is just wrong (form my point of view)

Comment: And of course I will have a discussion with customer about it (I will suggest users simply use Ctrl+C).
I just wanted to make sure I was not missing some native LS capabilities.

Comment: When/where is clipboard content pasted Ctrl+V? What you described in comment would work without clipboard: user selects documents, agent runs for selected documents and creates/updates notifications based on selected documents. Where comes clipboard into play?

Comment: Clipboard - does not play at all. I do not think anybody will use it at all.
It will be just button that does Ctrl+C + msgbox in a view and that's it.
No logic behind it.
I'm sure customer will accept fact that it is not really smart decision to make that button.

Comment: I see. Just in case you have to code it then create a formula button with 1.  @Command([EditCopy]) and 2. @Command([RunAgent]; "LotusScript agent which works on selected documents and builds the msg and tags")